# iPhone App to read Facebook wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, rss

I want to create an iPhone app that displays (among other things) a specific Facebook wall.  For a good user experience I didn't want an app that required the user to have a Facebook account and I didn't want to force the user to have to log in to Facebook to see the latest "news" in the app.  I started out by getting the wall RSS feed and tried parsing it ... I can "see" all the data I need ... but that is getting complicated quickly and has too many variables that are making the final results less than stellar.  I have read through the Facebook iOS programming tutorials and it seems to me like the SDK forces the user log in, which I don't like.

My question ... Is there a way to use the Facebook SDK with hard coded profile credentials to access a specific wall without forcing the user to login?  If possible, is that a recommended approach?  Any other ways to skin this cat?

I have read through the Facebook tutorial and searched through many postings on this site but haven't found an answer to this ... sorry if this a newbie question and has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item I.2. of the [Facebook API policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) list says

> You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects
>   Facebook usernames or passwords.

It sounds to me like that's what you're proposing to do; i.e., the user will be able to see a certain wall, but using hard coded credentials (not their own).  In other words, your credentials are proxying for the user.

I do not know if it is technically possible to do this (I imagine it is) but I don't think it's a good idea, and I do think it's a violation of the Facebook API terms of service.

Comment: Thanks ... that makes sense.  It didn't "feel" right ... but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the a access_token by parsing your app id and secret.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET

Then send following request to get the data you want. Note that only public data will be accessible.

https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Thanks ... I think this way be a way around the proxy problem.  If I can use the API to get public data that just might work!